# Hide dates in MVC bootstrap datetimepicker based on another datetimepicker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have two datetimepickers for start date and end date. I want to hide all dates before today in the start date datetimepicker and then I also want to hide all dates before the start date in the end date datetimepicker.

I am doing this in mvc and using the bootstrap pickers.

Answer (score 0):

Give the startdate to the datepicker: [start date property.](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate)

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({ startDate: startDate });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your datepicker can have the following properties among others, in your view -

```
   <input max-date="datePicker1.maxDate" min-date="datePicker1.minDate" ng-change="onDatePicker1Change()" ng-model="details.fromDate"/>
```

and the second date picker could be

```
<input max-date="datePicker2.maxDate" min-date="datePicker2.minDate" ng-change="onDatePicker2Change()" ng-model="details.fromDate"/>
```

In your controller activation, initialize appropriate scope values for datePicker1.maxDate, datePicker1.minDate, datePicker2.minDate and datePicker2.maxDate.

Add a onDatePicker1Change() function within the controller which will reset the values for datePicker2.minDate and datePicker2.maxDate appropriately.